# MySQL query that returns only the "common" columns for a group of rows (and PHP if needed)

Tags: mysql

I need to build a MySQL query that returns only the common columns for a group of rows. I've a table named **projects** that has id_country, id_auto, id_prov and id_pobl. I select a group of projects by an area with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT codpais, codauto, codprov, codpobl
FROM projects
WHERE area=1
```

This returns me:

```
id_country | id_auto | id_prov | id_pobl
155        | 1       | 4       | 31
155        | 1       | 4       | 10
155        | 1       | 4       | 25
```

But from the query above I only want the results that are equal on each row: id_country, id_auto and id_prov. One option will be return id_pobl as NULL if is not same result. If id_auto, id_prov or id_pobl is not the same on each result I don't needed. If the id_country is different, I needed it anyway.

I explain this because my English is not good so you can understand me. In my website I need to print the common country / province / city... of a group of projects. For example, if 155=Spain, 1=Comunidad de Madrid, 4=Madrid and 31, 10 and 25 are cities of the province of Madrid I only need to show (in the website): Spain / Comunidad de Madrid / Madrid. If only id_country and id_auto are the same on each row, I will show: Spain / Comunidad de Madrid. If each id_country is different, I'll show the countries separated by comas, like: Spain, Portugal, France...

Well I'm saying the names but I need the ids and later I'll do the JOIN/LEFT JOIN

Update, example:

I have a group of 5 projects that every project has a id_country, id_auto, id_prov and id_pobl. When I have to show it in PHP, I've to show the common country, auto, prov and pobl.

If the country, auto, prov and pobl are the same in every project I'll need to show in the HTML rendered page with PHP:

```
Country / Auto / Prov / Pobl
```

If the country, auto and prov are the same in every project but pobl is different, I need to show:

```
Country / Auto / Prov
```

If the country and auto are the same but prov and pobl are different, I need to show:

```
Country / Auto
```

If the country are different in every project, I need to show the list of countries:

```
Country 1, Country 2, Country 3...
```

Wish that now is more clear!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you want to achieve. Can you show an example of the output your hoping to get?

Comment: Will it always just be these columns?

Comment: Hello @Neville K and @dmcnelis: I've added an example of the output that I need in PHP/HTML with the 4 possible cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a grouped query. Something like:

```
SELECT codpais, codauto, codprov, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT codpobl) AS pobl 
FROM projects 
WHERE area=1
GROUP BY codpais, codauto, codprov
```

Comment: Hello @dnagirl, thank you. I've googling about a (BLOB) result (I see it on Navicat) and I don't understand what exactly is. Can you explain me it, please? And if I had to do the same you're doing with pobl with codato and codprov I will need to reproduce the same like `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT codprov)` and then only `GROUP BY codpais, codauto`?

Comment: @udexter: I expect Navicat shows you a BLOB because it doesn't have space to display a long string.  I don't use Navicat, but I bet doubleclicking on the BLOB would display the string. Regarding your groupings, you can put `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fieldname)` around codauto and codprov as well, but change the `GROUP BY` to just codpais.